# How can I apply a timezone offset provided through JS?

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp, utc

Let's say I detect the users timezone offset with:

```
var tz = (new Date).getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

and send the value of `-5` to PHP, so:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$tz = $_POST['tz']; // -5
$date = strtotime('now');
```

I want to store the timestamp as UTC in the database, but when displayed to the user I want to apply the timezone offset. So assuming `$tz` is `-5` for EST, how can I apply it to the timestamp in order to display a `date('M d Y H:i')` in my local timezone ?

**Bonus question:** How can I have it show time for PST only? I assume by finding the PST offset and just specifying a hardcoded PST number to the equation that will be used in the original answer.